# Create Dataframe columns from list

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, list, dataframe

*Disclaimer: Beginner* 
Will delete if there's a duplicate question already been posted

I'm looking to create a script that will grab data from multiple webpages and store it as columns in a dataframe.
As you can see from below, I can successfully grab data for one stock, I am wondering does anybody have an idea to modify this so I could use something like

```
stocklist = ["AMZN", "GOOG", "TSLA"]
```

Script below:

```
from time import sleep
from selenium import webdriver
import pandas as pd



driver = webdriver.Chrome('/chromedriver')

stock_list = ['AMZN']
values = []
metrics = []
def stocks():
    for i in stock_list:
        driver.get(f"http://finviz.com/quote.ashx?t={i}")
        value = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//td[@class='snapshot-td2']")
        metric = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//td[@class='snapshot-td2-cp']")
        for i in metric:
            metrics.append(i.text)

        for a in value:
           values.append(a.text)





def frames():
    d = pd.DataFrame({'Metrics': metrics,'AMZN': values})

    print(d)
    d.to_csv("AMZN.csv")
```

Ideally would like to create a column for each new stock and their corresponding values.
Currently outputs like below:

```
         Metrics     AMZN
0          Index  S&P 500
1            P/E   116.67
2      EPS (ttm)    20.93
3    Insider Own   11.20%
4   Shs Outstand  498.00M
..           ...      ...
67         SMA20    2.96%
68         SMA50   10.13%
69        SMA200   27.34%
70        Volume  689,073
71        Change    0.93%
```

Comment: Can you give us an example of what part of your dataframe is supposed to look like?

Comment: you want to take all columns names in list ..?

Comment: Apologies, description of output added

Comment: Just do `d = pd.DataFrame({stock_label: value_list for stock_label, value_list in zip(stock_list, values)}, index=metrics)`

Comment: Nope, I'm afraid that just gave the first values from the table over and over, layout was good though                                                                                                   `AMZN    GOOG
Index         S&P 500  116.67
P/E           S&P 500  116.67`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's is very simple :

```
from selenium import webdriver
from time import sleep
from selenium import webdriver
import pandas as pd

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"/chromedriver")

df = pd.DataFrame()

stock_list = ["AMZN", "GOOG", "TSLA"]

for stock in stock_list:
    values = []
    metrics = []

    driver.get(f"http://finviz.com/quote.ashx?t={stock}")
    driver.implicitly_wait(10)

    page_metrics = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//td[@class='snapshot-td2-cp']")  
    for metric in page_metrics:
        metrics.append(metric.text)

    page_values = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//td[@class='snapshot-td2']")
    for value in page_values:
        values.append(value.text)

    metric_column = 'Metrics_'+stock   
    df[metric_column] = metrics
    df[stock] = values

df.to_csv("finviz.csv")
```

Just go through the code you'll understand. This is output in sheet :

[image]

I have left one part for you to figure out and fix  -  I am writing `'Metrics'` column for `each stock` - you can change it to single column if that's your requirement.